# Android, cannot get my Bitmaps to fit properly inside ImageView using Glide and SetImageBitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-glide, android-bitmap

I am having issues on several places where I need to fit either a smaller image into a larger ImageView or the opposite. The Glide options like FitCenter, Override and such don't seem to make any difference.

Here's the first screen

[image]

Loading the Bitmap (from gallery) with this code. The image is 284x177

```
        val glideOptions = RequestOptions().override(binding.selectedImage.width, binding.selectedImage.height).fitCenter()
        Glide.with(binding.selectedImage).load(currentPhotoURI).apply(glideOptions).into(binding.selectedImage)
```

And this is the imageView

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selected_image"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/background_gray" />
```

Here's another case, the image is now larger, 400x249, but it still doesn't fit as it should. It's a recycler view item.

[image]

```
       val glideOptions = RequestOptions().override(itemBinding.imageImageView.width, itemBinding.imageImageView.height).fitCenter()
            val imagePath = if (image.progressImagePath == "") {
                image.edgesImagePath
            } else {
                image.progressImagePath
            }
            Glide.with(itemBinding.imageImageView)
                .load(imagePath)
                .apply(glideOptions)
                .transition(withCrossFade())
                .into(itemBinding.imageImageView)
```

And here's the xml, nothing special

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            tools:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

This is rather trivial matter, and I'd expect that the things I've tried would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Nothing is visually changing no matter the options I use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add scale type in ImageView of XML, will let you override image view scale type

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected_image"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```